# A few questions about KSVD algorithm (dictionary learning) in a paper

Tags: paper-review

To learn more about dictionary learning, I am currently trying to understand the concept in detail and to do so, I've found the following paper quite informative:

[KSVD: an algorithm for designing overcomplete dictionaries for sparse representation](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~elad/publications/journals/2004/32_KSVD_IEEE_TSP.pdf)

I have a few questions:

- does the jth column of D (the overcomplete dictionary) correspond to the jth row of X or its transpose? (where $Y=DX$, Y is our data/signals; D is the dictionary; X is the sparse represenation of signals) So we do work on the transpose of X and not the matrix X itself? Why the notation $x_T ^K$ is used and not $x_K ^T$ ?
- somewhere in the middle, they suggest to initialize $w_k$ which defines as follows:
  $$w_k=\{i|1 \leq k \leq K: w_k(i) \neq 0\}$$
  is defining this variable necessary in spite of the fact that we will
  define another variable afterwards. $\Omega _k$ is a matrix of size
  $N$ (number of signals (Y)) $\times |w_k|$ where it is one for
  $w_k(i)$ and zero otherwise. why do  we need to define $w_k$?

Comment: [Also posted on Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1285920/14578), where you eventually received an answer.
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.